# I receive the output 0.0 even though i should receive number values

Tags: java

Please help. I am trying to find the batting average and also the on base percentage. My output ends up being 0.0 for both no matter the numbers i put in, but when i use a calculator i end up getting something different. Also in my instructions i am told to input the numbers as integer values and to round my output to the nearest thousandths place.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Prog52d
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
  Scanner kbReader=new Scanner(System.in);
 //input
  System.out.println("Enter Player's Name");
  String name=kbReader.next();
  System.out.println("Enter Number of Times at bat.");
  int timesAtbat=kbReader.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter Number of Hits.");
  int hits=kbReader.nextInt();
  System.out.println ("Enter Number of Walks.");
  int walks=kbReader.nextInt();
  //calculates the batting average 
  double battingAverage=hits/timesAtbat;
  battingAverage= Math.round(battingAverage*1000.0)/1000.0;
  //calculates the on base percentage 
  double onBasepercentage= (hits+walks)/(timesAtbat);
  onBasepercentage= Math.round(onBasepercentage*1000.0)/1000.0;

  System.out.println("Player "+name+ " has a ");
  System.out.println("batting average of " + battingAverage + " and");
  System.out.println(" an On Base Percentage of " + onBasepercentage);
}
}
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Because both of the variables that you're printing are double m.

Comment: what do you mean? how do i fix it?^

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the code

```
 double battingAverage = hits / timesAtbat;
```

where `hits` and `timesAtBat` are ints.  This invokes int-based division, which will only return int values.  Then the int value will be cast to a double.

Since one can't get more hits than times at bat, most people will have a scenario that looks like this

```
double battingAverage = hits / timesAtbat;
double battingAverage = 30 / 150;
double battingAverage = 0;
double battingAverage = 0.0;
```

You need to cast the `hits` and `timesAtBat` to doubles to get a double-based division.

```
double battingAverage = ((double)hits) / ((double)timesAtbat);
double battingAverage = ((double)30) / ((double)150);
double battingAverage = 30.0 / 150.0;
double battingAverage = 0.2;
```

Your other problems are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Int/int = int (spoken in types), so you have  to either read your Input values as  double or convert them afterwards but before the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 double battingAverage=hits/timesAtbat;
```

This gives you an integer result because both `hits` and `timeAtbat` are integer.

Cast at least one of them to `double` to promote the datatype of your outcome to double as well:

```
 double battingAverage = (double)hits / timesAtbat;
```

**Or**

```
 double battingAverage = hits / (double)timesAtbat;
```