# Java Triangle Class

Tags: java, class, object

I am new to object and classes. I am creating this test program to get the area of the triangle. I kept getting 0 as the area. I have no idea where did I get it wrong.

```
public class Project1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle();

        System.out.println("The area of the triangle with base "
            + triangle1.base + "and with width "
            + triangle1.width + " is " + triangle1.getArea());
    }
}

class Triangle {
    double base = 1.0;
    double width = 1.0;

    double getArea() {
        return  1 / 2 * base * width;
    }
}
```

Comment: Integer division is the likely culprit. Try replacing `1/2` with `1.0/2.0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

You are computing `1 / 2`.

This is **integer division** which does **not support** decimal values. It always rounds towards zero, the result is thus

```
1 / 2 = 0
```

Because of that the computation gets `0` too.

---

### Solution

You can fix it by dividing decimal values instead of integers:

```
return  1.0 / 2.0 * base * width;
```

There is no integer division as soon as one of the operands is a decimal value like a `double` or `float`. You indicate `double` by adding the *dot* like `2.0`.

Alternatively you could use the decimal value `0.5` right from the start:

```
return 0.5 * base * width;
```

Note that both versions are equally fast since the compiler will pre-compute such constant computations at compile-time. The bytecode will thus have `0.5` for both versions.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following

```
 double getArea() {
        return  1/2 * base * width;
    }
```

To

```
 double getArea() {
        return  0.5 * base * width;
    }
```

Due to integer division 1/2 yields 0.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `double` numbers at `getArea()` method something like this:

```
double getArea() {
    return  1.0 / 2.0 * base * width;
}
```

Comment: Not wrong but not very useful without an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common mistake for Java beginners, and I admit I sometimes still make this mistake. When divide one integer by another integer in Java, the result will be an integer as well. So while you expect 1 / 2 will be 0.5, the result will be 0 (i.e. it is truncated). You could cast the number first to force the division to use float or double like:

1 / (float) 2
1 / (double) 2

Or use the shorthand:

1 / 2f
1 / 2d

where f cast the number before it to float, and d to double.