# Showing a percentage between 2 integers

Tags: android, math

I have a quiz game and i wanna show the percentage of level and maxlevel.

- (levelvideo) is my first integer of current level
- (QuestionLibraryVideo.mChoices.length) is my max level from length of table..

I try to show `this = (levelvideo/QuestionLibraryVideo.mChoices.length)*100` 
but shows me only zero.

```
thsekato2.setText(Integer.toString((levelvideo/QuestionLibraryVideo.mChoices.length)*100));
```

Comment: You are dividing two integers which will yield an integer result. Try casting one of your values to a double

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you divide integer by integer, you will loose decimals after `,`.
For example `3/2` is 1, beacuse it's 1,5, so integer have only 1.
Use `float` or `double` instead.

```
 float f1 = levelvideo;
 float f2 = QuestionLibraryVideo.mChoices.length;
 zero.thsekato2.setText(Integer.toString((int)((f1/f2)*100)));
```

Comment: so i need to convert this 2 integerts to float?

Comment: @Marios see answer now

Comment: i convert this to integerts to float and works like a charm! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this only with integer arithmetic, you can multiply the numerator by 100 before dividing.  It doesn't have the precision offered by converting to a double, but then, it doesn't have the overhead of type casting either.  This would look something like:

```
thsekato2.setText(Integer.toString((100*levelvideo)/QuestionLibraryVideo.mChoices.length));
```