# java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero, logic error?

Tags: java

Hi so maybe i'm not seeing the where the error lies or maybe i don't know java well enough to know the execute order of operations but can someone explain to me why it is going wrong?

I'm trying to write a code to simply calculate the minimum grade you would have to get to get your wanted grade on ex a module in a course if you know your weight on your grades and one of the grades already.

//calculate minimum grades

```
public int calculateMinimumGradeWith2Ass1unknown (int Grade1, int Weight1, int WeightOnNext, int WantedOverAll){

    int val1 = Grade1*(Weight1/100);
    int estimate = WantedOverAll-val1;
    int Grade2 = estimate/(WeightOnNext/100);

    return Grade2;
}
```

I appriciate any kind of help :)

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the stack trace, and identify the statement in your code that throws the exception.  What is the value of `WeightOnNext`?

Comment: use doubles not ints

Comment: Something is zero.  Probably `WeightOnNext`.

Comment: In ints, `5/3 == 0` It looks like you have a problem when `WeightOnNext ` < 100

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division of integers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Comment: @dehasi Isn't 5/3 == 1 instead of 0?

Comment: either `Weight1` or `WeightOnNext` is ==0

Comment: @Antoniossss `Weight1` is not the point here, because there is no dividing by `Weight1` in that method.

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal I meant `3/5` ;)

Answer (score 4):

First things first, in Java variable names are written with a lowercase character first (camelCase).

And class names are written with an uppercase character first (PascalCase).

---

Now to the exception. `WeightOnNext / 100` is probably so small that, with **integer division**, it will be rounded to zero. And then you take `estimate` and divide it by `0` which yields the exception.

```
int Grade2 = estimate / (WeightOnNext / 100);
```

Just exchange all the `int`s with `double`s and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the problem is in the following part of the code:

```
int Grade2 = estimate/(WeightOnNext/100);
```

It would be helpful if you included sample values that cause that exception, but you need to be aware that `int`s doesn't support fraction part, they just cut it.

So, when `WeightOnNext` is less than `100`, the `(WeightOnNext/100)` will always be cut to `0` and it will cause an exception when `estimate/0;` is performed.

For example:

```
WeightOnNext = 50;
```

`50 : 100 = 0.5`, but the fraction part (`.5`) is being cut, so there is `0` as a result of assigning to `int` variable.

You should consider using `double`s for such operations to support fraction parts.

---

By the way, you should follow naming coventions of Java language - names of variables should be written in *camelCase* to make you code more readable for others and even for you, in the future.