# Precedence in expression including parentheses and int cast in java

Tags: java, casting, parentheses

I have the following expression in my code

> int n = ((int) Math.sqrt(4 * 4 + 5) - 1) / 2;

Can someone tell me the precedence  in which the expression is evaluated?

Logically I would evaluate the expression in the following way:

1. 4 * 4 + 5 = 16 + 5 = 21
2. Math.sqrt(21) ~ 4.58
3. 4.58 - 1 = 3.58
4. (int) 3.58  = 3
5. 3 / 2 = 1.5

However the code evaluates to 1.

Comment: Did you google "java operator precedence" already? Please do some research before posting here ([oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)).

Comment: Yes I did but it did not help me because the problem was integer division (step 5) and not precedence.

Comment: Right. But then you could have precised your question and not ask for precedence :) You should also state such things to show research effort. Else you might get down-voted for lack of research.

Comment: I honestly thought the problem was precedence. So would it be better just to ask whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. The only difference (which doesn't matter for the result) is that the cast is evaluated
before the subtraction, and you're using integer division:

1. 4 * 4 + 5 = 16 + 5 = 21
2. Math.sqrt(21) ~ 4.58
3. (int) 4.58 = 4   (cast first)
4. 4 - 1 = 3
5. 3 / 2 = 1 ([integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java))

Answer (score -1):

The order you suggest is correct.
The keypoint is the last operation: the result of an `int` divided by an `int` is an `int` as well.
To fix this, one of the two number should be a `float` (or a `double`):

```
float n = ((float)(int) (Math.sqrt(4 * 4 + 5) - 1)) / 2;
```

In this way you divide a `float` by an `int`, and the result will be a `float`.
Or better:

```
double n = (Math.sqrt(4 * 4 + 5) - 1) / 2;
```

Because the cast to int of `Math.sqrt()` isn't useful.
Please note that the first operation does exactly what you ask with the round of the Math.sqrt(), while the second one doesn't.

Comment: The order is not entirely correct though. The cast is executed earlier.

Comment: What cast is executed earlier?

Comment: How about just interop with `1F` and `2F` instead of float casts?

Comment: The `int`-cast is done before the `- 1`. But OP thought its done after. See the answer of @that_other_guy.

Comment: Missread the example! Good point.