# Fraction calculations

Tags: java, expression, fractions

I have tried the code below so many times but I am always getting the answer as `11.0`.

**This is an error as the answer should be** `10.83` and I don't want to round off. How should I tackle this?

**Here is the code**

```
public class Question_4_Expression_Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double a = 10;
            double b = 7/3;
            double c = 12/8;
            //double x = ((a)+(b)-(c));
            System.out.println("Result is "+ (double)(x);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Division of integers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)