# Multiplication of int with float resulting wrong

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     int tempC = input.nextInt();
     float tempF = (tempC * 9 / 5) + 32;
     System.out.println(tempF);
   }
}
```

**Expected output** - 109.4

**Current output** - 109.0

Why decimal value  set to zero?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Division of integers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Comment: *"Multiplication of int with float resulting wrong."* - The problem is that you are NOT multiplying an int and a float.  You are multiplying and dividing ints!

Comment: Design question: Why is `TempC` an int if you expect temperatures to have fractional parts? Making it a float too would automatically solve the problem in the computation.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Why decimal value set to zero?"*

The reason this is happening is because the division of two *int* values will result in an integer value, as opposed to a real—*float* or *double*.

You can remedy this by appending the *float* or *double* literal-suffix, to the end of either of those values.

Here is an except from the *Java Tutorials*.
*[Primitive Data Types (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)*.

> *"... A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f; otherwise ... double and ... letter D or d. ..."*

Only one literal-suffix is required, per arithmetic statement.  So the following will suffice.

```java
tempC * 9 / 5f
```

As a final note, you *could* specify a *double* by simply writing it as *5.0*.
Although, you would then have to change *tempF* to a *double*.

```java
double tempF = (tempC * 9 / 5.0) + 32;
```