# Java REST service that accepts list of objects

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have to write a REST Service method that accepts a list of objects as parameter to calculate something and return a result.

I have so far:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "generateBill/{id}/{rates}")
public String generateBill(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable Rate rates[]) {
   // do things
   return "OK";
}
```

But I am sure that `@PathVariable Rate rates[]` is wrong.

I have to write the client part too and I also have no idea how to do it. It is the first time I have to write such a REST Service method.

Edit: Rate looks like this:

```
public class Rate {
   Long version;
   Double amount;
   Date validFrom;
   Date validUntil;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "generateBill/{id}/{rates}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String generateBill(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable Rate[] rates) {
   // do things
   return "OK";
}
```

Or second one (more Java style;) ):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "generateBill/{id}/{rates}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String generateBill(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable List<Rate> rates) {
   // do things
   return "OK";
}
```

This one you can call like this:

**GET:** `http://localhost:8080/public/generateBill/1/1,2,3,4`
Where 1.2,3,4 replace with your values, it depends od that what exactly is Rate ;)

---

**EDIT**

After your update, it looks like that you want to have POST method (you are posting list of rates) and then here is already answered question.
[receiving json and deserializing as List of object at spring mvc controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012841/receiving-json-and-deserializing-as-list-of-object-at-spring-mvc-controller)

Comment: Ok, so I was not very wrong ;P But as of the client? How do I pass the list in the url?

Comment: If there is array, then it will be converted to List ;)

Comment: Check my edit. But if you need to pass your object, better for you is using first solution ;)

Comment: Ok but my problem is that Rate is an object with different properties (see my edit) so I don't know how to add that list to the url.

Comment: So, then it will be POST and you will posting JSON object ;) In this case, you have make POST and set that you are want map your Rate class. Here is already answered question with examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012841/receiving-json-and-deserializing-as-list-of-object-at-spring-mvc-controller

Answer (score 4):

You should put your objects in the body of a `POST` request instead of using the URL :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "generateBill/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String generateBill(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody BillingRequest billingRequest) {
   // do things
}
```

Also, mapping directly a collection in the payload is not evolvable (you cannot add new "fields" outside the array), it's generally a good practice to wrap your array in a JSON object :

```
public class BillingRequest {
    List<Rate> rates;
    // Here you could add other fields in the future
}
```

Your HTTP request to call your service would look like this :

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
{  
  "rates" : [
     {
       "version" : 1,
       "amount" : 33.3,
       "validFrom" : "2016-01-01",
       "validUntil" : "2017-01-01" 
     },
     {
       "version" : 2,
       "amount" : 10.0,
       "validFrom" : "2016-02-01",
       "validUntil" : "2016-10-01" 
     }
   ] 
}
```

One last piece of advice about your model :

- Use `java.time.LocalDate` (or jodatime) instead of `java.util.Date`. If you need date+time, use `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (`DateTime` if you use jodatime)
- Use `java.math.BigDecimal` to represent exact numbers. Floating point numbers like `Double` [can lose precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977638/loss-of-precision-after-subtracting-double-from-double)

---

**EDIT** : I would suggest using `Instant` rather than `ZonedDateTime`, which is a timestamp with UTC timezone. Unless of course your domain requires different timezones.

Comment: Thank you very much! I accepted the other solution because he answered first but I think yours should be accepted too but I can't accept two..

Answer (score 2):

Other solution is to use JSON String format as a parameter and parse it afterwards. Something like

`[

   {

      "rates":1,
      "name":"rate1"
   },
   {

      "rates":2,
      "name":"rate2"
   },
   {

      "rates":3,
      "name":"rate3"
   }
]`

and after that parse the json to your object.