# Java double precision with constant multiplication/division

Tags: java, double, bytecode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retain precision with Doubles in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java)

Do you know the difference between these two operations in Java.

```
final double m1 = 11d / 1e9; // gives 1.1e-8
final double m2 = 11d * 1e-9; // gives 1.1000000000000001e-8
```

I see in the generated bytecode that the precompiled result of m2 is already not what I expected.
In the output of `javap -verbose -c` I can see the following value :

```
const #3 = double   1.1E-8d;
[...]
const #6 = double   1.1000000000000001E-8d;
```

When I use m1 or m2 in other expressions, I don't have the same result.

When I try the same thing in C, m1 and m2 is strictly 1.1e-8

I think my problem is in the way java handles double precision computation but I can't explain myself what I miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference you have is that 1e9 is exactly representable and 1e-9 which is not exactly representable. A small representation error results in an arithmetic error which you can see.

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1e9));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1e-9));
```

prints

```
1000000000
1.0000000000000000622815914577798564188970686927859787829220294952392578125E-9
```

The difference is not whether you have used `*` or `/` but that you have used a whole number in one case and a fraction in the other.

```
System.out.println(11 * 1e9);
System.out.println(11 * 1e-9);
```

prints

```
1.1E10
1.1000000000000001E-8
```

Comment: Ok that's the explanation for Java but now why when I execute the same code in C I have all precision I needed ?

Comment: The C compiler will optimise the code *much* further than `javac` will.  This can mean that it could translate `/ 1e-9` to `* 1e9` because a) its faster and b) more accurate.  Java's compiler does very little optimisations, this is left to the JIT which also means the de-optimised and optimised code must do the same thing, otherwise you would see a change in behaviour while the program is running. The conversion of a `double` to a String is different in C and Java as well, but it is less likely to be the cause of the difference. In both cases, they use the same FPU.

Comment: Also the C compiler could make use of the 80bit floating point registers/computation your computer has. This is platform dependant and only available on x86/x64 processors. Java will behave the same on every platform so will only use 64-bit floating point even if 80-bit floating point is available.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between Java and C, both respect the IEEE floating-point standard. The only difference can be the way you print it. The exact number 1.1e-8 is not representable as a `double`. The difference in output may be attributed to the details on how the error of representation was accumulated, and to what rounding is used to print the result.

Comment: I think the difference is only in how much error was accumulated, where the second line just steps over the threshold that is printed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use BigDecimal as below :

```
BigDecimal a=new BigDecimal(1e-9);
BigDecimal b=new BigDecimal(11);
System.out.println(a.multiply(b).toString());
```

you will see that your number is

```
1.10000000000000006850975060355784206078677556206457666121423244476318359375E-8
```

JVM rounds up your number and change it to :

```
1.1000000000000001e-8
```