# Pure Java code to convert an IEEE 754 double to string

Tags: java, string, double, ieee-754

I have a 64-bit `long` containing an IEEE 754 representation of a `double`. I'd like to convert it to a string just like the standard Java `Double.toString(d)` does. However, I can't use any of the methods of the `Double` class, because they are buggy. (`String.valueOf(d)` and `"" + d` don't work either, because they use `Double.toString(d)` internally. `NumberFormat` doesn't work, because it loses precision.) So I need pure Java code which would do the conversion.

Where can I find such code? I tried the source code of GNU Classpath, but it uses a native method for this conversion.

Comment: Can you elaborate in what way the `Double` methods are buggy? (Out of interest)

Comment: In that exotic JVM implementation `Double.toString(d)` doesn't return enough digits, i.e. it formats `ABC.DEFGH` as `ABC.DE` . I need all the digits.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty ugly. Does it have to be fast?

Comment: *"because it loses precision"*  I am pretty sure precision is lost the moment we represent numbers as IEEE 754.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched a bit and I found that: [dtoa.java](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/rhino/js/1.6R6/js-1.6R6-sources.jar!/org/mozilla/javascript/DToA.java?format=ok).
It seems complicated, but the code is under the GPL license (or the Mozilla Public License 1.1 license).

I hope it will help you.

(I even found the [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4511638) you refer to.)

Edit:

[Andrew Thompson] is right, you often (always?) lose precision with floating point.
As pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322875/1564493), you might want to use [`BigDecimal`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: Thank you for finding dtoa.java for me, I've just +1ed your answer. Ugh, it's indeed complicated.

Comment: Well, you didn't see the [http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c](`C version`)... It has a lot and a lot of prepocessor directives.

Comment: No, we don't always lose precision with floating point, e.g. with IEEE 754, if the numbers are 50-bit integers, then calculations are exact. But that's not the typical case. In the typical case, there is a loss of precision.