# Weird Java math execution

Tags: java, math

I have an weird issue.  I'm trying to store the result of an equation into a double variable.

```
double s = (((100 + 1)*(1/3))/100 + (1/3));
```

This returns a value a 0 rather than .67 (the correct value calculated from a calculator).  Any reason why this could happen?

Note:  A solution of saying that I could just make s = .67 is not a solution,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add `d` after all your numbers, eg `100d`, you'll use floating point operations, not integer ops.

Comment: As it is already answered, I am just adding a side-note that if you want precise value of `0.67` unlike something like `0.669999999999` you should use `BigDecimal`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following uses integer (i.e. truncating) division, the result of which is zero:

```
1/3
```

To get floating-point division, turn either of the argument into a double, e.g.

```
1.0/3
```

Thus, the overall expression becomes:

```
double s = (((100 + 1)*(1./3))/100 + (1./3));
```

`1.` is the same as `1.0`. Other ways to express the same number as a `double` are `1d` and `1D`.

The above expression evaluates to `0.6699999999999999`.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how I let this slip.  Thanks so much.  It's been bugging me for quite some time.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler sees your numers as int's..

try like this:

```
double s = (((100d + 1d)*(1d/3d))/100d + (1d/3d));
```

now the result will be:

0.6699999999999999