# Different values in calculating harmonic sum from left to right and right to left

Tags: java, double-precision

When calculating harmonic sum of numbers from 1 to 50000 in java in both directions, the values obtained must match but it is blowing my mind that they don't!
Kindly tell me why is it happening so.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int maxD = 50000;
        double suml2r=0, sumr2l=0;
        for(int i=1; i<=maxD; i++){
            suml2r += (double)(1)/i;
            sumr2l += (double)(1)/(maxD-i+1);
        }

        System.out.println("left to right = " + suml2r);
        System.out.println("right to left = " + sumr2l);
    }
}
```

Output:
left to right = 11.397003949278504
right to left = 11.397003949278519

Comment: It's to be expected since floating point values aren't exact representations of numbers. There's probably [100s of similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point). You should probably also read something like ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and/or ["Binary floating point and .NET"](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) (the latter is C#, but the same applies to Java).

Comment: You get the same problem with `0.1+0.2+0.3` and `0.3+0.2+0.1`. Mess around adding each pair of numbers and you'll have a better idea of why it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point is not precise! In the right to left sum you're adding from smallest to largest, and the least significant remnants have a change to accumulate, unlike in the left to right sum where a longer part of the mantissa needs to be dropped for the smallest added numbers. There's a reason why equality check for exact float values is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Different rounding-up and rounding-down applied after summing up your `double` values yield these results. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java) you should probably use `BigDecimal` if precision should be accurate.