# JUnit test case failure

Tags: java, junit

Here is my JUnit code for a test case of the cube root method I created that implements Newton's method:

```
@Test
public void standardCase_negative64e9() {
  double n = -64E9;
  double result = csc143.newton.Roots.cbrt(n);
  double delta = n * 1E-8;
  assertEquals("Standard cube root -64E9", -4.0E3, result, delta);
}
```

When I do the tests for all my test cases (using DrJave IDE) I only get a failure for this test case, and it reads:

```
Failure: java.lang.AssertionError: Standard cube root -64E9 expected:<-4000.0> but
was:<-4000.0000000003124>
```

I feel this has something to do with my "delta" value (which is `-640` in this case) because when I replace "delta" with `640` (instead of `-640`) in the `assertEquals()` method, I do not get a failure...

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java. It should be reopened.

Comment: You might have more success if you also explain _why_ @ItayMaman...

Comment: You don't see answers in the re-open queue @SteveP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `delta` has this value: `-64E9*1E-8` which is actually `-64`.That is: it is a negative value.  As `delta` is expected to be the upper limit on the difference between the actual and expected value you need to make it a positive number.

Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java#L591) of the `Assert` class. The place where doubles are compared is the `doubleIsDifferent` method:

```
static private boolean doubleIsDifferent(double d1, double d2, double delta) {
    if (Double.compare(d1, d2) == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((Math.abs(d1 - d2) <= delta)) {    
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you can see the relevant expression is `Math.abs(d1 - d2) <= delta`. As it uses  `Math.abs` the left-hand side is always 0 or positive. Thus it can never be less than a negative value so this method always returns `true` thus indicating to the caller (`assertEquals`) that your values are different.

In other words: change the definition of delta to:

```
double delta = Math.abs(n * 1E-8);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [Javadocs of JUnit Assert, assertEquals](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.String,%20double,%20double,%20double%29), you'll see that `delta` should indeed be positive:

> Asserts that two doubles or floats are equal to within a positive delta.

Comment: Then why is one of my earlier test cases not encountering the same issue:
    @Test
    public void standardCase_negative1000() {
      double n = -1000;
      double result = csc143.newton.Roots.cbrt(n);
      double delta = n * 1E-8;
      assertEquals("Standard cube root -1000", -10.0, result,delta);
    }