# Java error on simple multiplication

Tags: java, floating-accuracy

I'm currently in the process of learning Java. I have just run the following line in Eclipse in Win7 using jre1.8.0_25:

```
System.out.println(4.5 * 7.9);
```

The console output is: `35.550000000000004`

I'm just wondering why the output is wrong.

Comment: You should read up on int, double and float precision points

Comment: Welcome to floating point arithmetic!
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: This is normal floating point behavior.  If you need precision use BigDecimal.

Comment: possible duplicate: (floating point numbers) http://stackoverflow.com/q/322749/2777098

Answer (score 1):

When looking for accuracy, doubles are not the best choice, as they are actually not as perfect as they may seem due to some limitations in their design.

See http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/

Answer (score 1):

It's not only a Java issue (feature?), it's a common issue for all languages with floating point arithmetics. It's based on IEEE 754 standard, in case you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of loss of precision due to operations made by the computer in binary. You can see an explanation of it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0).

Comment: It's also because of imprecision in the input literals. 7.9 cannot be represented accurately in floating-point.