# Addition in Java

Tags: java, math

Was debugging a piece of code and found this strange issue .

On addition of two double variables 0.0040 and 0.0005, Java return me the result as "0.0045000000000000005"

Here's my piece of code :-

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 0.0040  ;
    double b = 0.0005;
    double result = a+b ;
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output : 0.0045000000000000005

The output is correct if I give value between 0.0041 to 0.0044 for variable "a" . However, If I give the value to variable "a" as 0.0045  it gives output as "0.004999999999999999".

Help needed !!

Comment: Search needed!   Floating point math!  Always happens!

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java

Comment: If you look around a bit, you'll find that Stack Overflow gets roughly eleventy billion questions a day from people like you who don't understand that floating point math isn't exact. It makes me wonder why schools don't teach this simple concept on day one.

Comment: The oldest one (or nearly the oldest one) in the book...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do exact floating point arithmetic in Java using [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Here is an example:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.0040");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.0005");
BigDecimal sum = a.add(b);
```

Also note that `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` (the same for integers) are immutable.

Comment: Is it not possible by using double ? Can you give me the same example in BigDecimal

Answer (score 2):

It's because of floating point numbers, they lose precision and cause the problem you are seeing. Rather use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for precision

Comment: Is it not possible by using double ?

Can you give me the same example in BigDecimal

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the other question (the one marked as duplicate at the top) as it as a much more in-depth answer. Regarding examples of BigDecimal, googling "BigDecimal tutorial" would return a lot of results, here's one such site: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-calculate-monetary-values-in-java-double-vs-bigdecimal/