# Wrong double value after arithmetic operation

Tags: java

```
double n1 = -6.0;
double n2 = 6.78;
System.out.println(n1 + n2);
```

I received the out put as `0.7800000000000002` instead of `0.78`.

Any idea why?

[Sample](https://ideone.com/q2nyOO)

Comment: That's just how floating point arithmetic works.

Comment: Even better: http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/572670

Comment: Can some other gold badger reopen and close as the new link? http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/572670 I have the hammer only once :(

Comment: Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java