# Why is this code giving me a strange output

Tags: java, int, double

The method below was written to make a String version of a number, I know there are already methods that do this, such as `String.valueOf()`, `Double.toString()`, or even just `"" + someNumber`.

```
private static String numToString(double i) {
           String revNumber = "";
           boolean isNeg = false;
           if (i == 0) { //catch zero case
               return "0";
           } 

           if (i < 0) {
               isNeg = true;
           }

           i = Math.abs(i);
           while (i > 0) { //loop backwards through number, this loop 
               //finish, otherwise, i would not get any output in 'main()'
               revNumber += "" + i % 10; //get the end
               i /= 10; //slice end
           }

           String number = ""; //reversed
           for (int k = revNumber.length() - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
               number += revNumber.substring(k, k + 1);
           }

           revNumber = null; //let gc do its work

           return isNeg ? "-" + number : number; //result expression to add "-" 
           //if needed.
       }
```

Although the above method should only be used for ints (32-bit), I made it accept a *double* (64-bit) argument and I passed a double argument, without a decimal, the output results are the same if I pass an *int* into the method as well, or with a decimals, etc...

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   double test = -134; //Passing double arg
   System.out.println(numToString(test)); //results
}
```

Result: (Maximum memory results for double?):

-323-E5.1223-E33.1123-E43.1023-E43.1913-E43.1813-E43.1713-E43.1613-E43.1513-E43.1413-E43.1313-E43.1213-E43.1113-E43.1013-E43.1903-E43.1803-E999999999999933.1703-E999999999999933.1603-E999999999999933.1503-E999999999999933.1403-E9899999999999933.1303-E999999999999933.1203-E999999999999933.1103-E8899999999999933.1003-E9899999999999933.1992-E999999999999933.1892-E999999999999933.1792-E999999999999933.1692-E999999999999933.1592-E999999999999933.1492-E999999999999933.1392-E999999999999933.1292-E999999999999933.1192-E999999999999933.1092-E999999999999933.1982-E999999999999933.1882-E1999999999999933.1782-E999999999999933.1682-E999999999999933.1582-E999999999999933.1482-E999999999999933.1382-E999999999999933.1282-E1999999999999933.1182-E1999999999999933.1082-E2999999999999933.1972-E2999999999999933.1872-E3999999999999933.1772-E2999999999999933.1672-E1999999999999933.1572-E2999999999999933.1472-E999999999999933.1372-E999999999999933.1272-E1999999999999933.1172-E2999999999999933.1072-E2999999999999933.1962-E1999999999999933.1862-E999999999999933.1762-E999999999999933.1662-E999999999999933.1562-E999999999999933.1462-E999999999999933.1362-E999999999999933.1262-E999999999999933.1162-E999999999999933.1062-E999999999999933.1952-E999999999999933.1852-E999999999999933.1752-E999999999999933.1652-E999999999999933.1552-E999999999999933.1452-E999999999999933.1352-E999999999999933.1252-E999999999999933.1152-E999999999999933.1052-E9899999999999933.1942-E9899999999999933.1842-E999999999999933.1742-E999999999999933.1642-E999999999999933.1542-E999999999999933.1442-E999999999999933.1342-E999999999999933.1242-E999999999999933.1142-E9899999999999933.1042-E999999999999933.1932-E8899999999999933.1832-E9899999999999933.1732-E8899999999999933.1632-E8899999999999933.1532-E8899999999999933.1432-E999999999999933.1332-E9899999999999933.1232-E8899999999999933.1132-E7899999999999933.1032-E8899999999999933.1922-E8899999999999933.1822-E7899999999999933.1722-E6899999999999933.1622-E5899999999999933.1522-E5899999999999933.1422-E6899999999999933.1322-E6899999999999933.1222-E6899999999999933.1122-E7899999999999933.1022-E7899999999999933.1912-E7899999999999933.1812-E8899999999999933.1712-E8899999999999933.1612-E7899999999999933.1512-E7899999999999933.1412-E6899999999999933.1312-E6899999999999933.1212-E7899999999999933.1112-E7899999999999933.1012-E7899999999999933.1902-E7899999999999933.1802-E6899999999999933.1702-E7899999999999933.1602-E7899999999999933.1502-E8899999999999933.1402-E8899999999999933.1302-E8899999999999933.1202-E8899999999999933.1102-E7899999999999933.1002-E7899999999999933.1991-E9899999999999933.1891-E9899999999999933.1791-E8899999999999933.1691-E7899999999999933.1591-E8899999999999933.1491-E8899999999999933.1391-E999999999999933.1291-E9899999999999933.1191-E9899999999999933.1091-E999999999999933.1981-E999999999999933.1881-E999999999999933.1781-E999999999999933.1681-E999999999999933.1581-E1999999999999933.1481-E999999999999933.1381-E999999999999933.1281-E1999999999999933.1181-E2999999999999933.1081-E999999999999933.1971-E1999999999999933.1871-E999999999999933.1771-E2999999999999933.1671-E3999999999999933.1571-E3999999999999933.1471-E2999999999999933.1371-E2999999999999933.1271-E2999999999999933.1171-E999999999999933.1071-E999999999999933.1961-E999999999999933.1861-E999999999999933.1761-E999999999999933.1661-E999999999999933.1561-E999999999999933.1461-E8899999999999933.1361-E8899999999999933.1261-E8899999999999933.1161-E7899999999999933.1061-E7899999999999933.1951-E7899999999999933.1851-E7899999999999933.1751-E7899999999999933.1651-E7899999999999933.1551-E6899999999999933.1451-E6899999999999933.1351-E6899999999999933.1251-E6899999999999933.1151-E6899999999999933.1051-E7899999999999933.1941-E6899999999999933.1841-E7899999999999933.1741-E7899999999999933.1641-E9899999999999933.1541-E999999999999933.1441-E999999999999933.1341-E999999999999933.1241-E999999999999933.1141-E999999999999933.1041-E999999999999933.1931-E9899999999999933.1831-E999999999999933.1731-E999999999999933.1631-E8899999999999933.1531-E9899999999999933.1431-E9899999999999933.1331-E8899999999999933.1231-E8899999999999933.1131-E8899999999999933.1031-E7899999999999933.1921-E7899999999999933.1821-E7899999999999933.1721-E6899999999999933.1621-E7899999999999933.1521-E7899999999999933.1421-E8899999999999933.1321-E7899999999999933.1221-E7899999999999933.1121-E8899999999999933.1021-E8899999999999933.1911-E9899999999999933.1811-E999999999999933.1711-E999999999999933.1611-E999999999999933.1511-E999999999999933.1411-E1999999999999933.1311-E2999999999999933.1211-E3999999999999933.1111-E2999999999999933.1011-E2999999999999933.1901-E3999999999999933.1801-E2999999999999933.1701-E2999999999999933.1601-E3999999999999933.1501-E2999999999999933.1401-E3999999999999933.1301-E3999999999999933.1201-E4999999999999933.1101-E5999999999999933.1001-E4999999999999933.199-E3999999999999933.189-E3999999999999933.179-E3999999999999933.169-E4999999999999933.159-E4999999999999933.149-E4999999999999933.139-E4999999999999933.129-E4999999999999933.119-E4999999999999933.109-E4999999999999933.198-E4999999999999933.188-E4999999999999933.178-E3999999999999933.168-E3999999999999933.158-E3999999999999933.148-E3999999999999933.138-E3999999999999933.128-E4999999999999933.118-E3999999999999933.108-E3999999999999933.197-E3999999999999933.187-E3999999999999933.177-E4999999999999933.167-E3999999999999933.157-E3999999999999933.147-E3999999999999933.137-E3999999999999933.127-E3999999999999933.117-E4999999999999933.107-E5999999999999933.196-E5999999999999933.186-E5999999999999933.176-E4999999999999933.166-E4999999999999933.156-E4999999999999933.146-E4999999999999933.136-E3999999999999933.126-E3999999999999933.116-E3999999999999933.106-E3999999999999933.195-E2999999999999933.185-E1999999999999933.175-E2999999999999933.165-E2999999999999933.155-E2999999999999933.145-E2999999999999933.135-E3999999999999933.125-E4999999999999933.115-E4999999999999933.105-E2999999999999933.194-E1999999999999933.184-E2999999999999933.174-E2999999999999933.164-E2999999999999933.154-E1999999999999933.144-E1999999999999933.134-E2999999999999933.124-E2999999999999933.114-E2999999999999933.104-E3999999999999933.193-E3999999999999933.183-E3999999999999933.173-E2999999999999933.163-E2999999999999933.153-E999999999999933.143-E2999999999999933.133-E2999999999999933.123-E2999999999999933.113-E3999999999999933.103-E3999999999999933.192-E3999999999999933.182-E3999999999999933.172-E3999999999999933.162-E4999999999999933.152-E4999999999999933.142-E5999999999999933.132-E6999999999999933.122-E7999999999999933.112-E6999999999999933.102-E6999999999999933.191-E7999999999999933.181-E8999999999999933.171-E8999999999999933.161-E8999999999999933.151-E9999999999999933.141-E8999999999999933.131-E8999999999999933.121-E43.111-E43.101-E43.19-E1000000000000043.18-E1000000000000043.17-E43.16-E43.15-E43.14-E43.143100.04310.0431.043.14000000000000004.30.4

Comment: i never is less than 0 in your loop.

Comment: `i /= 10` will not "slice end" of a double.

Comment: This might work for int, but not sure this would work with doubles. How do you handle decimal points?

Comment: The point is, the unexpected results, also the loop ends, otherwise, not output would be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not because of the complier. It is happening because you are doing

```
i /= 10; //slice end
```

So when you do 13.4 after the first run it wont give you 1.34 it will give you something like 1.339999999999999999 which is 1.34.

Check [Retain precision with double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java) for more details.

If you just want to reverse the number you can do

```
private static String numToString(double i) {
        String returnString = new StringBuilder(Double.toString(i)).reverse().toString();
        return i>=0?returnString:"-"+returnString.substring(0,returnString.length()-1);
}
```

Comment: That's probably true but doesn't have anything to do with the problem. The problem is that the break condition of the loop is `i > 0` which is (theoretically) never reached. It doesn't matter if the value becomes exactly 1.34 or 1.33999... because it's still > 0.

Comment: This is not a problem *at all*: the value of `i` is used only in the `i % 10` operation which isn't affected.

Comment: @Juhana please try this code with a breaking condition of i > 1 it will still be a problem ! I tried it and the output was -43.14000000000000004.30.4. Can you explain why this happens ?

Comment: The loop breaks, otherwise, no output would be shown at all!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (; i > 0; ) { //loop backwards through number
    revNumber += "" + i % 10; //get the end
    i /= 10; //slice end
}
```

This loop never finishes until it breaks at a much later time than it should. `i % 10` doesn't cut off the end of a double. It works well with an `int` but not with a double. Hence the 134->13.4->1.34->.134-> etc.... So you get an `argumentoutofrange` exception or something similar to that. Else the compiler just keeps doing it for the max memory that a double can handle.