# Variable displayed incorrectly

Tags: java, variables, console-application

I have a problem with my application output. I looked for some related posts but I couldn't find anything.

I use a method that looks like this:

```
setPercent(score/max score * 100):
```

Where both score and max score are double. Whenever I set the score as 29 and the max score as 100, for some reason it outputs 28.99999996.

What I've tried: casting 100 as double, making score and max score as ints.

If you need any additional info. just let me know.

Thanks,
zryw141

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java

Comment: In Java, if you want to make avoid this precision issue, your have to try BigDecimal.

Comment: I used the BigDecimal and it worked. I wasn't aware of such issue with precison loss before. Thanks a lot!