# Variable type for precise calculations (JAVA)

Tags: java, math, discrete-mathematics

What is the best type variable for more precise calculations?

> I've used double in BigDecimal and were not accurate.

Comment: BigDecimal has arbitrary precision.  Define "not accurate".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retain precision with double in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java)

Comment: It is a common misconception that you need `BigDecimal` or that i will fix all the problems you have with `double`  IMHO using `BigDecimal` just makes find errors harder in many cases as well as being slower.

Answer (score 2):

A common mistake is calling

```
double d = ....
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
```

e.g.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(0.1);
System.out.println(bd);
```

prints

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

This produces a precise representation of the double which is often not what was intended.  Instead you should use

```
double d = ....
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
```

As this produces the BigDecimal for the shortest decimal value which would be this `double`

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1);
System.out.println(bd);
```

prints

```
0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

if by *accurate*, you mean precision:

**the precision can not be infinite** (or you should use another symbolical representation).

When you use some functions:

1 you have to define precision (which can be very big).

2 you have to take in consideration rounding mode also.

And in many cases, math libraries can not predict precision result, if you reuse values for further calculations. So you have to track the precision.

Example with 1/3, and 100 decimals:

```
// 1/3
BigDecimal one=new BigDecimal(1);

BigDecimal three=new BigDecimal(3);

BigDecimal one_third=one.divide(three,100,RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN); // third parameter is round mode

System.out.println("1/3="+one_third);
```

gives:

1/3=0.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333

Comment: You always need to consider rounding whether you sue double or bigDecimal. +1

Comment: thanks. I put some "precision". +1