# Why java calculation double error?

Tags: java, double, decimal, calculation

Why java calculation gives (double)40395.075*100=4039507.4999999995 instead 4039507.5 ? how to handle this in calculation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` class to handle such cases. It happens because of the way floating point values are stored in memory.

Comment: `java.text.DecimalFormat` might be useful

Comment: A `double` cannot hold the number 40395.075.  The best it can do is 40395.074999999997089616954326629638671875.  See http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work/showfloat.php?floatvalue=40395.075&floattype=double for an explanation.