# java simple double sum strange behaviour

Tags: java, double, precision

Please, can someone explain me what is the cause below the following behaviour? Because I really can't understand it

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java

Comment: which version of Java u are runnig. I got 0.52269815 not 0.522698150000000001 on jdk 7