# Java Double doesn't Multiply Correctly

Tags: java, android, integer, double, multiplication

I have a double and a integer value and I wan't to multiply them. My code look completely normal but I get wrong output. Is there something I don't know or is this a bug?

```
    double db = 1.2;
    int m = 3;
    System.out.print(String.valueOf(db*m));
```

My output is : 3.5999999999999996.

I need to get 3.6 as output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java

Comment: Can you give me the code?