# Rounding to Nearest Hundreth Double Subtraction

Tags: java, math, double, rounding, precision

I am trying to subtract two doubles from each other. I can't really change them to anything else as a lot of my project I am working on is already in doubles.

```
double numberOne = 0.7;
double numberTwo = 0.65;

return numberOne - numberTwo;
```

My unit test is throwing an error though. From the subtraction above I would expect to see 0.05 and or you know just .05.

```
Expected :0.05
Actual   :0.04999999999999993
```

I've been looking online for a solution and I just can't seem to find it.
All help is welcome, thank you!

Comment: Try and write `0.05` as a binary value. `return BigDecimal.valueOf(numberOne).subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(numberTwo)).doubleValue();`

Comment: Related / duplicates: [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/153724) and [Retain precision with double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322749)

Comment: Elliott Frisch thanks, alot that worked like a charm!