# How to subtract 2 floats in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, subtraction

I have a very strange problem in my Kotlin app :

```
14.9 - 12.8 == 2.0999994
```

I also tried to do :

```
var1 = 14.9
var2 = 12.8
var1.minus(var2)
```

but I strangely get the same result.

How can I subtract 2 floats in Kotlin and getting a decent value, like 2.1 in this case ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retain precision with double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java)

Comment: If the numbers are really of type float, the result is OK. You can expect only about 6 decimal digits accuracy.

Comment: those are double not float.

Comment: Blackbelt I declare them as float. I am going to try to cast them in double. Thanks !

Comment: @Elynad `double` will still give floating point inaccuracies same as `float`. You'll have to use `BigDecimal` for actual precision.

Answer (score 0):

This is a floating point error if you are not into financial calculations then you can use

```
var var1 = 14.9
var var2 = 12.8
var var3 = var1.minus(var2)
println("%.2f".format(var3))
```

Else try BigDecimal

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't want to just print or display the result, I also need to do some calculations with it.   But I am going to try the BigDecimal thing, thanks for the tip !