# Wrong result when calculating floats in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse gives the wrong result when trying to calculate the sum of two floats.
In my code, there are 2 float variables: `float from = 0.025` and `float to = 1`.
Then result has double variable: `double value = 7 * from / to`.
Eclipse compiler shows: `value = 0.174999997019767760`
In excel calculator, this result was `value = 0.175`

How can I solve this an issue?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java

Comment: Eclipse is just your development environment, it is Java that is giving you these results.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply due to your Java program not rounding the result the same way the excel calculator does. This is a result of the way computers handle floating point arithmetic. You have two options: round the result, or use the java `BigDecimal` class. If you want to round the result, you can use:

```
float from = 0.025f;
float to = 1;
double value = 7 * from / to;
DecimalFormat ds = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
double rounded = Double.parseDouble(ds.format(value));
System.out.println(rounded);
```

If you would rather not have to round, you can use the `BigDecimal` class.
[Java BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)