# Java stream sort reversed after sum

Tags: java, java-stream, comparator

```
list
.parallelStream()
.sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(r -> r.getA() + r.getB()).reversed())
```

get a compile error, `cannot resolve method r.getA()`, but

```
list
.parallelStream()                                    
.sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(r -> r.getA() + r.getB())
```

is ok,

so how can I do a sort by r -> r.getA() + r.getB() and get it reversed?

Comment: Specifying the type of `r` seem to solve the problem `.sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble((R r) -> r.getA() + r.getB()).reversed());`. Alternatively `.sorted(Comparator.<R>comparingDouble(r -> r.getA() + r.getB()).reversed());` also seem to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do that would be to type cast the `ToDoubleFunction` as:

```
list.parallelStream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble((ToDoubleFunction<C>) r -> r.getA() + r.getB())
            .reversed());
```

Though I would have preferred explicitly creating a `Comparator<C>` as

```
list.parallelStream()
        .sorted(((Comparator<C>) (o1, o2) -> Double.compare(o1.getA() + o1.getB(), o2.getA() + o2.getB()))
                .reversed());
```

***Note***: `C` here is your object type, which constitutes the `list` in question as well.

Comment: On a side note, the [precision of adding doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java) would still be a question that you shall look into.

Comment: IMHO, the link in that comment does not explain it enough. I'd recommend reading Knuth's algorithms (was it Knuth after all?) how important it is to start adding up with the smaller numbers and then adding the larger ones.

Answer (score 0):

**Here Is the three solutions of same problem.**

Bean Class

**Item.java**

```
public Item {

double lPrice;
double hPrice;

/**
 * @param lPrice
 * @param hPrice
 */
public Item(double lPrice, double hPrice) {
    super();
    this.lPrice = lPrice;
    this.hPrice = hPrice;
}

public double getlPrice() {
    return lPrice;
}

public void setlPrice(double lPrice) {
    this.lPrice = lPrice;
}

public double gethPrice() {
    return hPrice;
}

public void sethPrice(double hPrice) {
    this.hPrice = hPrice;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Item [lPrice=" + lPrice + ", hPrice=" + hPrice + "]";
}
}
```

**Driver Class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Item(1.0, 0.0));       list.add(new Item(3.0, 0.0));       list.add(new Item(4.0, 0.0));
    list.add(new Item(6.0, 0.0));       list.add(new Item(5.0, 0.0));       list.add(new Item(7.0, 0.0));

    System.out.println("Without Sorting...");
    list.forEach(System.out::println);

    list.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(i -> ((Item) i).getlPrice()+((Item) i).gethPrice() ).reversed());
    System.out.println("\n=== in descending order===");
    System.out.println("===Sort based on sum of lower price and higher price of item===");
    list.forEach(System.out::println);

    list.clear();
    list.add(new Item(1.0, 0.0));       list.add(new Item(3.0, 0.0));       list.add(new Item(4.0, 0.0));
    list.add(new Item(6.0, 0.0));       list.add(new Item(5.0, 0.0));       list.add(new Item(7.0, 0.0));

    list = list.parallelStream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(i -> ((Item) i).getlPrice()+((Item) i).gethPrice() ).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("\n=== Another Sol'n in descending order===");
    System.out.println("===Sort based on sum of lower price and higher price of item===");
    list.forEach(System.out::println);

    list.clear();
    list.add(new Item(1.0, 0.0));       list.add(new Item(3.0, 0.0));       list.add(new Item(4.0, 0.0));
    list.add(new Item(6.0, 0.0));       list.add(new Item(5.0, 0.0));       list.add(new Item(7.0, 0.0));


    list.sort((a1,a2) -> {
        double item1 = a1.getlPrice()+a1.gethPrice();
        double item2 = a2.getlPrice()+a2.gethPrice();
        return -Double.compare(item1, item2);
    });
    System.out.println("\n===Here is one more Solution===");
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
 }
```

**Output.**

Without Sorting...

Item [lPrice=1.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=3.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=4.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=6.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=5.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=7.0, hPrice=0.0]

=== in descending order===

===Sort based on sum of lower price and higher price of item===

Item [lPrice=7.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=6.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=5.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=4.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=3.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=1.0, hPrice=0.0]

=== Another Sol'n in descending order===

===Sort based on sum of lower price and higher price of item===

Item [lPrice=7.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=6.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=5.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=4.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=3.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=1.0, hPrice=0.0]

===Here is one more Solution===

Item [lPrice=7.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=6.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=5.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=4.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=3.0, hPrice=0.0]

Item [lPrice=1.0, hPrice=0.0]

[Here is complete picture of program with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW2H1.png)

Comment: If there is any error. Kindly let me know and provide the correct solution so everyone will get benefit of that.