# How to avoid accuracy loss while using jeval？

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I used jeval for some data computing tasks, and found a loss of accuracy. 
Is there any way to avoid accuracy loss while using jeval? 
I want to get the accurate result just like BigDecimal.

```
public class EvalTest {

    private static Evaluator eva = new Evaluator();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String formula = "780.0000000-259.9999998";
            String res = eva.evaluate(formula);

            BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(780.0000000);
            BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(259.9999998);
            BigDecimal c = a.subtract(b);

            System.out.println("a");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I use jeval, the formula "780.0000000-259.9999998" will get an result as "520.0000001999999", but if I use BigDecimal, I can get the accuracy result "520.0000002".

Comment: I guess that `jeval` uses `double`. You should trust to `BigDecimal` results.

Comment: But the reason I use jeval is I have scenarios which are much more complicateble than "780.0000000-259.9999998", like "(1+2)/3*4+5/6". 
jeval is a very convenient component for Mathematical operations.

Comment: @lulijun: it may be very convenient, but if you can't make it use BigDecimals, it simply won't deliver the results you want. You will have to live with a certain degree of inaccuracy.

Answer (score 1):

According to Jeval's Javadoc for the `evaluate(String expression)` method for Jeval 0.9.4, it says:

> "The result of the evaluated. expression. Numbers are treated as
>   doubles, so resulting numbers will contain at least one decimal
>   place."

You can't avoid accuracy loss when using doubles. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java).
Floating point numbers have this limitations. For example, you can see it for simple expressions like `5.6 + 5.8`, which yields `11.399999999999`.

Comment: Is there some else lib which can execute complex Mathematical operations as well as accurate operation?

Comment: Just found MathParser can't identity illegal formula. For example, '0/0' will get a result of '0'.

Comment: Just found the solution, expression.setSlientMode()