# Convert 2 decimal to integer

Tags: java, double, rounding

I want to convert number **2.55** to **255** in java.

I have tried the following code but I am getting **254** instead of **255**:

```
final Double tmp = 2.55;
final Double d = tmp * 100;
final Integer i = d.intValue();
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: where does the `2.55` come from? Right now the "correct" solution is to write `i = 255` - depending on where the input actually comes from and in what form the proper answer may vary.

Comment: What if you used a string?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to round that value, and you can use primitives for that..
i.e. use the primitive double instead of the wrapper class Double

```
    final double tmp = 2.55;
    final double d = tmp * 100;
    long i = Math.round(d);

    System.out.println("round: "+ i);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple by using `BigDecimal`

```
    BigDecimal bg1 = new BigDecimal("123.23");
    BigDecimal bg2 = new BigDecimal("12323");

    bg1= bg1.movePointLeft(-2); // 3 points right

    bg2= bg2.movePointLeft(3);  // 3 points left


    System.out.println(bg1);     //12323

    System.out.println(bg2);     //12.323
```

Answer (score 1):

the value of d is 254.999999999997.
this is a problem with floating point calculations.
you could use

```
i = Math.round(d);
```

to get 255.

--- delete the bottom.. was wrong

Comment: Your second proposal does not produce 255 but 2.